# Difference between haidager fringes and Newton rings?

Tags: interference

What's the difference between a Haidinger fringe and Newton's Ring? I know visually, the central fringe of a Newton ring is dark, whereas the central Haidinger fringe is bright, but what's the difference in physical set-up that would cause these different types of interference?

Answer (score 2):

For Haidinger fringes, the thin film has a constant thickness and the path difference is associated with a variable inclination of rays. With an extended source, localization is at infinity.

For Newton fringes, the thickness is variables and the inclination is constant. The path difference is associated with a variable thickness. With an extended source, localization is near the lens.

Sorry for my poor english.